# disconjugate difference equation

Tags: differential-equations

Definition: A self adjoint  difference equation
is defined by
\begin{equation}\label{self-adjoint1}
\Delta(p(t-1)\Delta y(t-1))+q(t)y(t)=0,\\ t\in [a,b+1]= \{a, a + 1, \ldots , b + 1\},
\end{equation}
Define a linear operator $L$ on the set $\{y: [a, b+2]\to \mathbb{R}\}$ by:
\begin{equation*}
 Ly(t)=\Delta(p(t-1)\Delta y(t-1))+q(t)y(t), \mbox{ for } t\in [a+1,b+1].
\end{equation*}

A self adjoint  difference equation $Ly(t)=0$ is "disconjugate" on $[a, b+2]$ provided that no nontrivial solution of $Ly(t)=0$ has two or more generalized zeros on $[a, b+2]$.

What are the methods used to check the disconjugacy of such equation (Any references)?
What is the link between the disconjugacy and the existence of solution to a boundary value problem?
Need some references (books) about the associated Green's function!

Thank you

Comment: Where do you encounter these terms?  (If in a paper, what paper?  If a book, what book?)

Comment: For disconjugate difference equations:[link]( https://www.jstor.org/stable/1997963) Hatman 1978